# How can I find out if a string is parseable with jodatimes DateTime constructor?

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to determine if an input string input can be parsed by jodatimes `DateTime` constructor `Datetime(Object instant)` but I'm not interested in creating the `DateTime` object at this time.

Is there any way to check if the string is parseable beside calling the constructor and catch the possible exception?

Comment: The `Datetime(Object)` constructor is a nightmare. `new DateTime(null) eq "now"`. Urgh.

Comment: Thanks for that note, I could easily have missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConvertManager.getInstance().getInstantConverter()` is what the constructor uses to see if there is a matching converted. However, it also thrown an exception.

But I that constructor would only consult the [`ISODateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html). If you want to specify a custom format:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
dtf.parseDateTime(dateTimeString);
```

Alas, again you'd have to catch an `IllegalArgumentException`